# Moving the shared screen image to the center on Skype

Tags: windows-7, skype

I'm skyping Bob. We both shared our WebCam. Bob has also shared his screen. How can I move his screen at the center? I tried to drag and drop but was unsuccessful.

[image]

I use Skype 6.18.0.106 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Did you try simply clicking it, when there are multiple people it just requires a click to bring that person in focus

Comment: @skv I am pretty sure I did but will try it next time, thanks!

Comment: Your also not using the current version you might want to try that